# How to use a INSERT INTO SQL Query with Dynamic parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Hello i have a method which saves some data in the SQL, but sometimes not every parameters are set, this gives me an exception becuase its NULL.

Here is my Method:

```
 public string getBookingURL(string guid, BookingRequest request, string token, out string exitURL)
    {

        if (validateToken(token))
        {
            string command = "INSERT INTO OUTLOOKADDIN (GUID, TOKEN, BOOKINGID, STARTUTC, ENDUTC, SUBJECT, NUMPARTICIPANTS) VALUES (@GUID, @TOKEN, @BOOKINGID, @STARTUTC, @ENDUTC, @SUBJECT, @NUMPARTICIPANTS)";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            connection.Open();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@GUID", guid);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TOKEN", token);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BOOKINGID", request.bookingID);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@STARTUTC", request.startUTC);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ENDUTC", request.endUTC);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SUBJECT", request.subject);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMPARTICIPANTS", request.numParticipants);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Dispose();
                cmd = null;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.Message + "\n\rStackTrace:\n\r" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

            HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
            string baseUrl = current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://"
                + current.Request.Url.Authority
                + current.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/');

            exitURL = baseUrl + "/index.html";
            return baseUrl + '/'
                + "WebPage/Booking/BBooking.aspx?"
                + "OPS"
                + guid; ;

        }
        exitURL = null;
        return null;
    }
```

i think that this SQL Query...

> string command = "INSERT INTO OUTLOOKADDIN (GUID, TOKEN, BOOKINGID,
>   STARTUTC, ENDUTC, SUBJECT, NUMPARTICIPANTS) VALUES (@GUID, @TOKEN,
>   @BOOKINGID, @STARTUTC, @ENDUTC, @SUBJECT, @NUMPARTICIPANTS)";

... should run dynamically or is there any other solution which prevents adding the parameter when its empty?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Can you set your columns as nullable in the database?

Comment: that the startutc date shuld be between 1900 - 2999... , the datetime is empty

Comment: i think that the datetime wont accept null, is that right?

Comment: I recommend using a stored procedure instead, I can help if you are interested in stored procedures

Comment: Unrelated Tip: If you use `using (SqlCommand cmd = ...) { ... }` then there is no need to call `cmd.Dispose();` and `Parameters.Clear()`

Comment: what error message are you getting? maybe the fields on the tables doesn't allow to have null values.

Comment: Error - SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Comment: I updated my answer. What you really need is validation code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [vignesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848841/vignesh)'s post, use `DBNull.Value` for null values, if the DB fields are nullable.

**EDIT:** It is probably better to check the values BEFORE you even get to your `getBookingURL()` method. If you do proper validation before reaching this point then you can avoid the whole problem altogether.

```
if (/* date is null or not valid */)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mydate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
else
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mydate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDate;
```

Comment: i tried your code, even if i let the datetime empty it shows me this date: {01.01.0001 00:00:00} how can i use this in my if statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can add validation in the front end to prevent empty values

or

you can check for null values before adding parameters

```
if(value!=null)
{
cmd.Parameters.Add("@GUID", guid);
} 
else
{
cmd.Parameters.Add("@GUID", "somestring or value");
}
```

Comment: what can i do when a datetime is empty?

Comment: you can use the ternary operators in all your command.Parameters.Add
for example instead of 
>> `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ENDUTC", request.endUTC)`
you can use 

>>
`cmd.Parameters.Add("@ENDUTC",
            (request.endUTC == null) ? (object)DBNull.Value : request.endUTC);`

similarly you can do for adding all the other parameters
_vote up if you find the above comment useful in someway_

Answer (score 0):

If your fields in the db table are unnulable, you must validate the values on the front end and show a warningto the user.

If the columns are nullable, you can send the DBNull to the database and it wont throw exception. My solution for it:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterName",
            (a == null) ? (object)DBNull.Value : a);
```